# Looping through different arrays lists

Tags: java, arrays, loops, arraylist

I have three different arrays of different sizes to gather node status and I would like to iterate through all of them with one loop instead of creating one for each. I've seen examples with naming the array as an integer and doing a while/for loop and incrementing, but I would like to find a method to keep the current array names. Here is what I have so far.

**EDIT :** I would like to keep all lists separate so that it is easily distinguishable what nodes have what status.. i.e.

Online - node1, node2 | Offline - node3, node4 | Unknown - node5, node6

```
private String nodeStatus() {

    List<Node> onlineNodes = new ArrayList<Node>();
    List<Node> offlineNodes = new ArrayList<Node>();
    List<Node> unknownNodes = new ArrayList<Node>();

    for(Node n : getNodes()){

        if (n.isRunning() == RunningType.ONLINE) {
            onlineNodes.add(n);
        }

        if (n.isRunning() == RunningType.OFFLINE) {
            offlineNodes.add(n);
        }

        if (n.isRunning() == RunningType.UNKNOWN) {
            unknownNodes.add(n);
        }
    }

    for (Node element : <online,offline,unknown>) {
        System.out.println(element);
    }

}
```

Comment: You don't have arrays but rather lists backed by arrays. Why not concatenate them together before iterating? It is a pretty cheap operation. Otherwise you need some useless logic checking for bounds while iterating the largest list.

Comment: Why not just keep a 4th list which is "all", and add every node to it?

Comment: Sorry all - I should have been more clear... I want to keep them separated.. Online, Offline, and Unknown would each be in their own list so it is easy to separate which nodes have which status. What is not shown here is that the node status is updated about every 30 seconds

Comment: @Jon So when you are iterating over the lists you need to know where the current element in the iteration is from?

Comment: What's the return type of `Node.isRunning()`?

Comment: @Arthur - that is correct

Comment: @shmosel - the return type is a string

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, what you want is to iterate through 3 lists on 1 `for-loop` w/o using a 4th list, the way you can achieve this is:

```
import java.util.*;

public class MultipleArraysLooping {
    public static void main (String args[]) {
        List <String> list1 = new ArrayList <String>();
        List <String> list2 = new ArrayList <String>();
        List <String> list3 = new ArrayList <String>();
        fillLists(list1, list2, list3);
        iterateLists(list1, list2, list3);
    }

    public static void fillLists(List <String> list1,
        List <String> list2, List <String> list3) {
        list1.add("item1 on list1");
        list1.add("item2 on list1");
        list1.add("item3 on list1");

        list2.add("item1 on list2");
        list2.add("item2 on list2");
        list2.add("item3 on list2");
        list2.add("item4 on list2");
        list2.add("item5 on list2");

        list3.add("item1 on list3");
        list3.add("item2 on list3");
    }

    public static void iterateLists(List <String> list1,
        List <String> list2, List <String> list3) {
        int size = 0;
        if (list1.size() > list2.size()) {
            if (list1.size() > list3.size()) {
                size = list1.size();
            } else {
                size = list3.size();
            }
        } else {
            if (list2.size() > list3.size()) {
                size = list2.size();
            } else {
                size = list3.size();
            }
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            if (i < list1.size()) {
                System.out.println(list1.get(i));
            }
            if (i < list2.size()) {
                System.out.println(list2.get(i));
            }
            if (i < list3.size()) {
                System.out.println(list3.get(i));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The output given by the above code is:

```
item1 on list1
item1 on list2
item1 on list3
item2 on list1
item2 on list2
item2 on list3
item3 on list1
item3 on list2
item4 on list2
item5 on list2
```

As you can see, it iterates over each list alternatively

I hope this helps, probably there's a better way to get the largest size of the arrays.

If what you want is to iterate the 3 of them in order (list 1 complete, then list 2 and lastly list 3) or by some state, well, you need to add your logic there

Answer (score 0):

You might want to keep a map of statuses to elements instead of having 3 separate variables. Assuming you have Java 8 and `getNodes()` returns a `Collection`, you can do something like this:

```
Map<String, List<Node>> elementsByStatus = getNodes().stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Node::isRunning));

// print all elements
elementsByStatus.stream()
        .flatMap(List::stream)
        .forEach(System.out::println);
```

If you need to iterate over elements by status, you can do this:

```
elementsByStatus.forEach((status, elements) -> {
    elements.forEach(element -> {
        //...
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You Can try by this:

```
public class ListIterator {

public static void print(List<String> list){

    for (String string : list) {
        System.out.println(string);
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<String> list1=new ArrayList<>();
    List<String> list2=new ArrayList<>();
    List<String> list3=new ArrayList<>();

    list1.add("List11");
    list1.add("List12");
    list1.add("List14");

    print(list1);

    System.out.println();
    list2.add("List21");
    list2.add("List22");
    print(list2);
    System.out.println();
    list3.add("List3");
    print(list3);
    System.out.println();




}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also try this:

```
public class ListIterator {

public static void print(List<String> list){

    for (String string : list) {
        System.out.println(string);
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<String> list1=new ArrayList<>();
    List<String> list2=new ArrayList<>();
    List<String> list3=new ArrayList<>();

    list1.add("List11");
    list1.add("List12");
    list1.add("List13");


    list2.add("B1");
    list2.add("B2");



    list3.add("C1");

    int a=list1.size();
    int b=list2.size();
    int c=list3.size();

    int max=Math.max(a, b);
    max=Math.max(max, c);

    //System.out.println("");

    for(int i=0;i<max;i++){


       if (i<list1.size()) {
           System.out.println(list1.get(i));
       }
       if (i<list2.size()) {
           System.out.println(list2.get(i));
    }

       if (i<list3.size()) {
           System.out.println(list3.get(i));
    }

    }





}
}
```